# Issue with TFS Nugetter and Build Definitions

Tags: tfs, nuget, nugetter

I've ran into an interesting little issue with TFS NuGetter. I've set up my build definition to use the NuGetter versioned template, downloaded TFS Versioning from CodePlex and (I believe) I have everything set up properly.  The issue I run into when I fire off a test build is the following:

> ***The invocation of the constructor on type 'TfsBuild.NuGetter.Activities.NuGetterProcess' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.***

I did a search and there was some information on CodePlex which points toward a PowerShell v1 assembly which needed to be installed within the GAC (which I did), but unfortunately I'm still hitting the same problem.

Have any of you seen anything similar? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

try updating Windows Management Framework from here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. I don't know if it was the PowerShell upgrade or something else. The build service logging only said that an exception was thrown in the `NuGetterProcess` constructor and had no information on the type of the exception and no stack trace.